# How to authenticate to frontend with jwt from backend?

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to implement jwt for authentication for my backend and frontend. I have 2 apps (.net core mvc) one is backend other one is frontend

I send login request and then i get access and refresh token etc. Those parts are ok.

**Question:**
But problem is that front end has no idea that i have token from backend API that's why there is no session created on frontend yet. So i cannot redirect user to protected areas of website [Authorize]

First thing comes to my mind is after i get access token from backend API ı should post it to front end controller via ajax. Lets say "/Account/Login" and this frontend controller will validate token (because it has same key with backend) then it will create session for this user and will return success from ajax call.

Is this correct approach for this kind of login flow ? Are there any alternatives ?

Answer (score 2):

How is your user talking with the backend app? Directly or through frontend app? I would presume that they make a request to the frontend app and the frontend talks to backend. In such a scenario frontend can easily create a session for the user and associate the token from backend with the session.

If the user is talking directly to backend app, then I would go with your idea - the backend app would have to somehow notify frontend app that it now has a token for the user.

Another solution is to create some shared session mechanism (there are some readily available solutions for that). Your backend app can create a shared session and associate the token with it, and then the frontend app can use the same shared session.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes client directly talks to backend api. I use frontend just to display data.I never heard about shared session before i will read about it now.